# jQuery id selector not returning empty array for non-existant element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm seeing an jQuery id selector return a single array item for an element that should be non-existant.

`$('#bootstrap_alert_placeholder')` in my function returns, (from the Chrome console)

```
[context: document, selector: "#bootstrap_alert_placeholder", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

But when I call the selector in my console to double check the output I see an empty array, which is what I would expect.

Anyone have idea of what is going on here? I would expect the function to execute with a different this context, but I don't see how that would effect the result of a selector.

Comment: Okay erm, not sure what the question is there.

Comment: All those properties exist on a jQuery object; empty or non-empty; what does the `length` property show?

Comment: Chrome console output of *array-like objects* is confusing. The thing contains no item, has `length: 0` but some other properties (most of them inherited from `$.fn`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in the console, on this page:

```
console.log($("#blah"));
//possible output in chrome: 
//[context: document, selector: "#blah_im_not_a_real_element", 
//constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]

//or in firefox: ({context:({}), selector:"#blah"})


 console.log($("#blah_im_not_a_real_element").length)
//outputs 0
```

the jQuery object is not "empty" as in `null` or `undefined`. it is empty as in 0 in length, is still a jQuery object though

```
console.log($("#blah_im_not_a_real_element").constructor)
```

Comment: Ah that is it, it is just that Chrome's console is confusing in this case. Thanks.